# Constant voltage source for unkown load

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-source

I am designing a circuit for maintaining constant voltage for an unknown load and measuring current through R5. Following is image for reference:

[image]

I had done some simulations on Tina before making the PCB with the components. The simulation worked as expected. After that I selected the OPA197 to drive the load and LMP7702 to give feedback to the control op-amp.

Now I have assembled the PCB. For testing purpose I have shorted the 100   ohm resistor and input of LMP7702.

When I apply for example 1V at the Input_Signal, Vout comes out ~536mV and output of LMP7702 comes at around ~884mV. This should obviously not happen as the LMP7702 is acting as buffer.

I have also tested both op-amps with +-5V supply and similar results are observed. I have changed the op-amps and tested again but same results.

I am not sure what to check. Power and input signals are within specs as per the datasheet. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. Any suggestion what the fault maybe and what to check?

Comment: "a circuit for maintaining constant voltage for unknown load" - this is commonly called a "power supply" and it rarely uses op-amps as the *output* driver.  Some designs use op-amps *internally* a few with very exotic requirements might use power ones.  **But why are you not using a conventional power supply module or at least design topology??**  What you've drawn in your schematic, frankly, makes no sense whatsoever.  You should start by reviewing more usual solutions to this problem.

Comment: Start by explaining what the ultimate source of power for the system will be (in terms of voltage, available current, and nature of the energy source - mains, battery, solar, whatever), what the required output voltage you want to maintain is, what the *maximum* current draw of the load can be, and what you want to have happen if the load tries to draw more than that.  Also explain what the load actually is, as no power supply is perfect and some loads have unique sensitivities to supply imperfections.

Comment: It is probably oscillating, to result in the weird DC measurements. But your load return is to a high impedance input which makes no sense whatsoever : I have no idea why simulating that did what you expect unless you expected to see Vout = U1 output (which just tells you there is no power delivered to the load). @Transistor is probably right about what you were aiming for.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry I was not clear. I have updated the schematic. I want basically control voltage across R5 and measure current passing through it. I am using 79xx and 78xx voltage regulators to power the opamps. And the maximum load drawn by the load is about ~10mA

Comment: Your circuit is a constant current generator and not a constant voltage generator.

Comment: Now your circuit has both R4 and R5 as unknown loads. I presume that R5 is known. Please take your time and fix up the question.

Comment: "*The unknown load is three electrode electrochemical cell.*" Which unknown load? You have two. "*The circuit is used to control voltage across R5 and measure current through it.*" If you're controlling the voltage across R5 then you can't measure the current through R5 with this circuit as usually you would use \$ I = \frac {V_{out}} {R_5} \$ but R5 is unknown so you've two unknowns, I and R and only one known, V.

Comment: @Transistor I am using transimpedance amplifier to measure current through R5. I did not mention it as I removed it for testing the Voltage control Circuit. Right now I am having this issue with the control circuit

Comment: OK. I give up then. We can't answer an incomplete question with details being added like this.

Comment: @Transistor I did not add the information about the other circuitry as it does not affect the circuit shown

Comment: @BrianDrummond I checked the Vout on the oscilloscope and it output was indeed oscillating. The output of U1 is square wave signal and output of U2 is triangular waveform. Maybe there is some parasitic capacitance in PCB layout? I added capacitor across negative feedback of U1 (2, 6 pin of U1) and stopped the oscillation. The circuit is stable now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use the test circuit from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp7702.pdf?ts=1602081852486&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) then you've got an error in copying the circuit.

[image]

*Figure 1. From the datasheet.*

[image]

*Figure 2. What you created.*

You have your load connected between U1 output and U2A non-inverting input. The input will have a very high impedance and the datasheet says the input bias current is 50 nA. You can't sink current into the non-inverting input.

---

Update after edit:

[image]

*Figure 3. Modified schematic.*

> I am designing a circuit for maintaining constant voltage for unknown load ...

No. This circuit will control the current, not the voltage.

> I had done some simulations on Tina before making the PCB with the components. The simulation worked as expected.

What did you expect? (You haven't told us.)

- What you should expect is that when stable the negative feedback should bring U1 inverting input to virtual ground. The voltage there should be really close to 0 V.
- Since R1 and R2 are both 10k that means that the output of U2A will be -1 × V<sub>in</sub>.
- Since U2A is configured as non-inverting buffer that means that V<sub>out</sub> will be -1 × V<sub>in</sub> too.
- This means that U1 will have to swing negative for a positive input signal.

> Now I have assembled the PCB. For testing purpose I have shorted the 100Ohm Resistor and input of LMP7702. When I apply for example 1V at the Input_Signal, Vout comes out ~536mV and output of LMP7702 comes at around ~884mV. This should obviously not happen as the LMP7702 is acting as buffer.

Try this:

- Leave R3 in circuit and short out R4.
- Set R5 = 1 kΩ. It will make the maths easy.
- Set the input to 2 V.
- If everything is working V<sub>out</sub> should go to -2 V. You'll have 2 mA going through R5.
- U1 output should be \$ \frac {100 + 1000} {1000} V_{out} = \frac {11}{10} V_{out} \$ (-2.2 V).

Update your question with your results and we'll go from there.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I have edited the schematic. To check the circuit I removed R4, R5 and shorted the 100Ohm resistor to the non inverting input of the U2. Simulation works perfectly fine. I am not sure why this circuit is not working @Transistor

Comment: I get an automatic ping when you comment on my answer. The ping syntax is `@username` without spaces (or else it doesn't work).